# BTstack on MSP430F5438A + CC2564 bluetooth module

Tags: msp430

First, is there any good documentation for the btstack API's. I am trying to learn how to fully use btstack , send and receive data, look for devices within range and initiate connection.I am implementing this for MSP-430F5438A + CC2564 Bluetooth module.

http://code.google.com/p/btstack/wiki/MSP430GettingStarted

This website has some examples, but I am still confused, I need someone to break it down for me.Is there a template that I can start of. Anything would be helpful. If there is a step by step reference on how to connect to a device and exchange packets, it would be really great. Thanks is advance

Answer (score 0):

In the regular "GettingStarted" page is a little explanation on what goes on in the packet handler, which is the main part of where you basically put all of your new code.